# Refresh widget(s)

Tags: perl, curses

If I have a window created like this

```
my $cui = new Curses::UI( -color_support => 1 );
my $win1 = $cui->add(
                     'win1', 'Window',
                     -y    => 0,
             );
```

How can I enforce changes made to its widgets.

I tried

```
$cui->refresh();
```

and

```
$win1->refresh();
```

Even

```
Curses::refresh($win1);
```

But they all cause fatal error

```
argument 0 to Curses function 'refresh' is not a Curses window at ....
```

Comment: `Curses::UI` is an event-based abstraction on top of curses. You need to wire your components together, bind keyboard shortcuts etc. and then start the main loop. Have you read the [tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI/Tutorial.pod)?

Comment: Yes. I call refresh() from event handlers

Comment: Alright then. I think [intellidraw](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI/Widget.pm#METHODS) is what you want. But not sure, long time since I used Curses::UI.

Comment: You are my saver man. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [kba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201318/kba). Widgets and windows should be scheduled for drawing like this

```
$win1->intellidraw();
...
$statusBar->intellidraw();
```